# Find normal basis for F390625 over F25.

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields

I am new to Field theory and want to do this problem , Can anyone give hint or reference on how to find Normal basis, I tried searching over the web but did not find any good resources

Comment: Is $390625=5^8$? Anyway, for any Galois field extension of finite degree, there is always a normal basis (that's the Normal Basis Theorem).

Comment: Yes it is , How to find the normal basis for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $K=\Bbb F_{5^2}$ and $L=\Bbb F_{5^8}$. Then $|L:K|=4$ and $\text{Gal}(L/K)$
is cyclic, generated by the Frobenius map $F:a\mapsto a^{25}$.

We get an action of the polynomial ring $K[X]$ on $L$ by defining
$$\left(\sum_i c_iX^i\right)\cdot a=\sum_i c_iF^i(a).$$
Then $L$ is annihilated by $X^4-1$ in this action

For $a\in L$ to be a normal basis, it is necessary and sufficient that
the annihilator of $a$ in $K[X]$ is generated by $X^4-1$. The annihilator
is a principal ideal, and is generated by a monic factor of $X^4-1$.
But $X^4-1$ factors completely over $K$:
$$X^4-1=(X-1)(X+1)(X-i)(X+i)$$
where $i^2=-1$ in $K$. So $a$ is a normal basis iff
$$\frac{X^4-1}{X-u}\cdot a\ne0$$
for each $u\in\{\pm1,\pm i\}$.

One can solve this by trial and error: keep throwing random $a$ at this until
one of them works. But we can use some more algebra to avoid work, as
$K$ has the fourth roots of unity, $L/K$ is a Kummer extension: $L=K(\sqrt[4]c)$
where $c$ is any non-square in $K$. The typical element of $L$ is
$$a=b_0+b_1\sqrt[4]c+b_2(\sqrt[4]c)^2+b_3(\sqrt[4]c)^3$$
with $b_0,\ldots,b_3\in K$.
Then
$$F(a)=b_0+jb_1\sqrt[4]c-b_2(\sqrt[4]c)^2-jb_3(\sqrt[4]c)^3.$$
where $j$ is either $i$ or $-i$. Repeating this, we see that
$a,F(a),F^2(a),F^3(a)$ are linearly independent iff $b_0b_1b_2b_3\ne0$.

Answer (score 1):

Apply the [iterative construction](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1304.0420.pdf) of a normal basis for the field extension $\Bbb F_{p^n} \mid \Bbb F_p$ for $p=5$, described on page $42$.